# Error Se ha encontrado un error PHP

Tags: php, vscode

Me arroja este error y claramente funciona el codigo correcto en otro equipo, pero al parecer ahora conmigo dejo de funcionar.

Mensaje: substr(): Pasar nulo al parámetro #1 ($string) de tipo string está en desuso

Nombre de archivo: bibliotecas/Rest.php

Número de línea: 91

adjunto codigo:

```
$this->rest_server = @$config['server'];

    if (substr($this->rest_server, -1, 1) != '/')
    {
        $this->rest_server .= '/';
    }
```

Comment: Parece que `$config['server']` no está definido, pero no se ve el error porque le antepones `@` y salta hasta que quieres manipular la cadena que debería llegar. Asegúrate de proporcionar un valor adecuado.

Comment: Silenciar los errores con `@` es una mala práctica, evítalo en cualquier caso. Aquí puedes intentar una asignación con fusión de null, algo así: `$this->rest_server = @$config['server'] ?? null;` y luego verificar el estado de la propiedad asignada: `if ( $this->rest_server && substr($this->rest_server, -1, 1) != '/' )`